# Raspberry Pi sudden shutdown, excessive heat

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, power-supply

I have a Raspberry Pi model 2 B with Raspbian.

When I plug in the power source, only the Green LED blinks, no Red LED.

The OS successfully boots and I can use the Raspberry perfectly. As soon as the power supply is plugged in, the Broadcom chip gets very, very hot, very fast. It burns when touched.

After 2 minutes of usage, the RasPi unexpectedly shuts down and after 3 minutes starts up again. It then continues in this loop forever.

I have re-formatted the MicroSD card and re-installed Raspbian many times.

I have installed a heat-sink to the Broadcom chip, and have tried with 3 different power supplies, 2 different USBs connected to my MacBook Pro 2014, connected to a USB-wall charger, and tried with an old BlackBerry charger of 5V and 700mA.

What is going on?

**EDIT**

Temperature measured with the command line function measured 90.7°C directly after booting.

Comment: I have a Pi2B which has been switched on for several hours.  I feel no heat from the Broadcom chip.  I think your Pi is dead or dying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Raspberry Pi is probably dying. The RPi can get pretty warm, roughly 80 C, without damaging the device. Since the device boots, you can run the command `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp` to get the current device's temperature. Currently, mine is sitting at 44.4 C, with a heatsink.

Run the command a few times spaced out over the couple minutes. If that temperature is rising until it dies, you've got a good indicator that the RPi needs to be replaced.

Comment: It marked 90.7 C in the first trial soon after it booted. It is probably broken right?

Comment: @PiloBasualdo: It is most definitely broken. I would **not leave it plugged in** for a long period. Please be kind to the planet and recycle it ;-).